# callback function is calling before all validation

Tags: php, codeigniter

Call back validation calling first then required validation is calling. I want to call required validation first.

My set_validation function  code:

```
public function set_validation()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from', 'Ended Date', 'required|callback_compareDates');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to alter the sequence of the execution you need modify the core library file in `/system/libraries/Form_validation.php`

From function

```
protected function _prepare_rules($rules)
{
...
...
return array_merge($callbacks, $new_rules);
}
```

**Change**

```
return array_merge($callbacks, $new_rules);
```

**To**

```
return array_merge($new_rules, $callbacks);
```

Read here [Form_validation.php](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Form_validation.php)

**OR**

Without modifying core, you have to create on more callback function which does function of rule `required` like below

```
function required($str)
{

    if(!is_array($str) ? (empty($str) === FALSE): (trim($str) !== ''))
    {
       $this->form_validation->set_message('from', 'Required error message');
       return false
    }

    return true;
}
```

and in your controller

```
public function set_validation()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('from', 'Ended Date', 'callback_required|callback_compareDates');
}
```